# typescript string or custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following:

```
type gio = {
    metadata: any;
}


let a:gio | string;
```

Problem: typing `a.metadata` produces the error `Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'string | gio'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` will take all properties which are included in both types - so its type will be the common properties between `gio` and `string`. Since `string` doesn't have a `metadata` propery it won't be included in the final type. What you need is `&`:

```
type gio = {
    metadata: any;
}

let a:gio & string;
```

That way the properties of gio and string will be combined and you will be able to access `a.matadata`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
type gio = {
    metadata: any;
}


let a: gio | string;

if(typeof a !== 'string'){
    a.metadata
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: [snaksa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67804303/8238184) using [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) will work, but the difference is `let a: gio & string` means any value `a` is set to will have to be a valid `gio` *and also* a valid string, meaning it has to have the metadata field *and also* all of the members of string (length, indexOf(), trim(), etc.).
It's similar to writing `interface MyNewType implements gio, string`

---

[From the docs:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)

> TypeScript will only allow you to do things with the union if that thing is valid for every member of the union.

For example if `gio` was defined as:

```
type gio = {
    metadata: any;
    length: number;
}
```

You could access `a.length` because both `gio` and `string` have a length field.
On the other hand, you can't access `a.metadata` because `a` could be a `string`, nor [`a.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), because it could be a `gio`

> The solution is to narrow the union with code ...
> For example, TypeScript knows that only a string value will have a typeof value "string":

So, [as Dor ben Itzhak answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67804045/8238184):

```
if(typeof a !== 'string') { 
   // a is not a string, therefore it is gio
    a.metadata
} else { 
   // a is a string
   a.indexOf("foo")
}
```

Or if you're you want to tell ts "trust me, it's a gio", you can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
(a as gio).metadata
```

For the record, [There's a whole section in the docs for more complicated narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)